# Alignment of atomic variables

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Naturally, in order for a typical modern processor architecture (like x86_64) to perform an atomic load or store, the data to be read/written needs to be aligned.

But how is this requirement actually realized/enforced via C++11 `<atomic>` variables?

Suppose I have an architecture that supports 16-byte compare and swap (double-word CAS), so it can atomically read/write 16-byte values, and I define a 16-byte type:

```
struct double_word
{
    std::uint64_t x;
    std::uint64_t y;
};
```

Now, suppose I include an `std::atomic<double_word>` as a member field of a class:

```
class foo
{
    public:

    std::atomic<double_word> dword;
};
```

How do I know `foo::dword` is actually aligned on a 16-byte boundary?  How do I know a call to `dword.load()` would actually *be* atomic?

Actually, I originally starting asking this question because of an odd thing that happened when I added another data member before `foo::dword`.  I defined `foo` as:

```
class foo
{
    public:

    std::uint64_t x;
    std::atomic<double_word> dword; 
};
```

When I actually perform an atomic load on `foo::dword`, and compile and run using GCC 4.7.2 on an x86_64 machine running Debian Linux, it actually gives me a Segmentation Fault!

Full program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

    struct double_word
    {
        std::uint64_t x;
        std::uint64_t y;
    };

    class foo
    {
        public:

        std::uint64_t x;
        std::atomic<double_word> dword; // <-- not aligned on 16-byte boundary
    };

    int main()
    {
        foo f;
        double_word d = f.dword.load(); // <-- segfaults with GCC 4.7.2 !!
    }
```

This actually segfaults on `f.dword.load()`.  At first I didn't understand why, but then I realized that `dword` is ***not*** aligned on a 16-byte boundary.  So, this leads to a lot of questions like: what should the compiler do if an atomic variable is not aligned and we try to atomically load it?  Is it undefined behavior?  Why did the program simply segfault?

Secondly, what does the C++11 standard say about this?  Should the compiler make sure that `double_word` is automatically aligned on a 16-byte boundary?  If so, does that mean GCC is simply buggy here?  If not - it would seem it is up to the user to ensure alignment, in which case *any* time we use an `std::atomic<T>` larger than one byte, it would seem we'd *have* to use `std::aligned_storage` to ensure it is properly aligned, which (A) seems cumbersome, and (B) is something I've never actually seen done in practice or in any examples/tutorials.

So, how should a programmer using C++11 `<atomic>` handle alignment issues like this?

Comment: It looks like defect of cooperation between compiler and library.  The code that should work by C++ standard segfaults.

Comment: GCC 4.7.2 is old, and before finalization of the C++11 standard. Please switch to a newer version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (in november 2014, [GCC 4.9.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/)) which would be much more C++11 conformant.

Comment: Like any other programmer, look at the compiler manual and see what the compiler assumes and how you should tell it to do what **you** want. Another reason to look at compiler manuals as they contain changelogs and notes on what features aren't complete... like Atomics in 4.7.2.

Comment: It's the implementation's responsibility to ensure that `std::atomic<T>` is suitably aligned, just as with every other standard library object. Your implementation is defective. [This is GCC bug #62259](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62259)

Comment: As rightly said Casey, this is an old bug #62259. In 4.9.3 it is not working: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s3zk69UAj3p26vzJ    But at 5.1 it is already working: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GvirSiavk1jEybeT

Comment: Yes, compiler should make sure the object is allocated with respect to the necessary alignment.  I believe the bug Casey pointed out is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is programmer's responsibility to make sure dword is 16bytes alignment. On 64bits platform, data is aligned in 64bits boundary unless you specify explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65147
Just adding `alignas(16)` is fixing the problem.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

struct double_word
{
    std::uint64_t x;
    std::uint64_t y;
};

class foo
{
    public:

    std::uint64_t x;
    alignas(16) std::atomic<double_word> dword; // <-- not aligned on 16-byte boundary
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    double_word d = f.dword.load(); // <-- segfaults with GCC 4.7.2 !!
}
```

Comment: I can't come up with a simplified code snippet that still exhibits the problem, but I have observed this bug occurring with production code in GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: I observed this bug in GCC 11.2.0, did you sloved ?